# 2 Digit Numbers in Command Line arguments Treated only as a Single Digit

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

Here is the code in my `average.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int total = 0;
  for(int i=1; i<argc; i++) {
    char cnum = *argv[i];
    string snum = "";
    snum += cnum;
    total += stoi(snum);
  }

  cout << "The average is " << total/(argc-1) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

When I run `./average 3 5 33`, the answer should round down to `13`, but instead, I get `3`. And when I run `./average 3 5 44`, the answer should round down to `17`, but I get `4`. I know that only the second digit of the argument is disregarded, but I am not sure as to how to include the second digit.

Comment: Since you are using C++, use std::stoi, std::stod etc. Remember to compile for C++11 or newer, e.g. on gcc or clang '-std=c++11'.

Comment: `argv[i][1]` will give you a secont digit.

Comment: Actually, you will find the third digit is ignored too.  In fact, everything except the first digit will be ignored!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char cnum = *argv[i];
```

This is taking the first character of the argument.  You don't want just the first character, you want the *whole* argument.  So just write:

```
    const std::string snum = argv[i];
    total += std::stoi(snum);
```

(You could write it as just:

```
    total += std::stoi(argv[i]);
```

This relies on implicit conversion from `const char*` to `std::string` - but it's often helpful when debugging to name intermediate values.)

Comment: I see. This way of converting a character into an integer is much more convenient than my method.

Comment: It isn't converting a *character* into an integer - it is converting a whole *sequence* of characters.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Just a hint: There is, too, [std::atoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi), accepting a char const* directly, avoiding the (in this case) entirely unnecesary (implicit or not) conversion to std::string...

Answer (score 1):

Does the following help?

```
  int total = 0;
  for(--argc; argc > 0 ; --argc) total += atoi(argv[argc]);
```

Comment: Though yours did help me solve the problem, it didn't explain why only a single digit was being used. I was sort of looking for a more in-depth answer.

Comment: I though 'atoi(argv[argc])' express just that. But never mind, I get your point.